# OOP : Does each child class get its own static variable if defined in Parent?

Tags: java, oop

Example

```
abstract class A
{
  protected static Queue<String> q = new ArrayList<String>();

  abstract void myAbstractMethod();

  public doConcreteThings()
  {
     //busy code utilizing a 'q'
     q.add("something");
     myAbstractMethod();
     //busy code
  }

}

class B extends A
{

  public void myAbstractMethdo()
  {
     //creates concrete implementation using 'q'
  }
}

class C extends A
{

  public void myAbstractMethdo()
  {
     //creates concrete implementation using 'q'
  }
}
```

- Will each extended class get its own static Queue?
- If not, how do I make sure that common functionality of a static variable is defined in the parent but each class gets its own static variable (hence a static Queue)

Comment: A static variable appears once per ClassLoader no matter how many sub-classes you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there will be one queue shared by all the classes. One way to do this would be to have a separate static queue in each sub-class and add another protected `getQueue()` method that returns this queue. That way each sub-class can have its own queue.

Note that `getQueue()` would be a non-static method but return a static variable reference. That lets you implement it in sub-classes, while its behavior is "effectively" like a static method (it does not require access to `this`).

```
abstract class A
{
  protected abstract Queue<String> getQueue();
  public abstract void myAbstractMethod();

  public doConcreteThings()
  {
     //busy code utilizing a 'q'
     getQueue().add("something");
     myAbstractMethod();
     //busy code
  }
}

class B extends A
{
  private static Queue<String> q = new ArrayList<String>();
  protected Queue<String> getQueue() { return q; }

  public void myAbstractMethod()
  {
     //creates concrete implementation using 'q'
  }
}

class C extends A
{
  private static Queue<String> q = new ArrayList<String>();
  protected Queue<String> getQueue() { return q; }

  public void myAbstractMethod()
  {
     //creates concrete implementation using 'q'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you John , I should try this. I was guessing something along these lines

Answer (score 3):

> Will each extended class get its own static Queue?

- No, static variables are bound to a particular class in which you
  define it. If you want different static variables for each of your
  child class, you would need to define them explicitly.

> how do I make sure that common functionality of a static variable is
>   defined in the parent but each class gets its own static variable

- That's not possible, as for the reason stated in the first case. Different classes don't share static variables. Rather different instances of same class share them.

However, you can access the `static` variables defined in `Parent` class in your `Child class` with the `Parent Class` name.

**WorkAround**: -

You can define `getters & setters (non-static)` for your `queue` in each of your `subclasses`, and also have different `static queue` for each of them. Now, everytime the method of a subclass is invoked (through polymorphism), it will return the `static queue` defined in that class only.

Answer (score 0):

No, static variables belong to the entity you define them in, even though they are abstract classes or interfaces.

I'd really want to challenge why you want the design you're proposing, but if you really want that each subclass their own (static) queue, you could do something like this:

```
abstract class A
{
  abstract Queue getQueue();

  abstract void myAbstractMethod();

  public doConcreteThings()
  {
     //busy code utilizing a 'q'
     getQueue().add("something");
     myAbstractMethod();
     //busy code
  }    
}

class B extends A
{
protected static Queue<String> q = new ArrayList<String>();

  public void myAbstractMethdo()
  {
     //creates concrete implementation using 'q'
  }
  public Queue getQueue() {
    return queue;
  } 
}

class C extends A
{
protected static Queue<String> q = new LinkedListList<String>();

  public void myAbstractMethdo()
  {
     //creates concrete implementation using 'q'
  }

public Queue getQueue() {
    return queue;
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are not like object variables when it comes to inheritance. For example: You have a super class with a static variable and a object variable. When you extend that class you can override the object variable, and it will be unique to that class, however this is not the same for a static variable. The static variable will be the same throughout all of the classes that extend the super class.

Answer (score 0):

- Will each extended class get its own static Queue? 
  No, they have access to the same Queue q that is in A.  So B and C both have access to q but the only instance of q is in A.